# Getting prime numbers, custom example

Tags: c++, algorithm, primes

I was tasked this in class today, so the teacher could judge where our skills are.

I am not an experienced C++ programmer, and I made a mistake on my sheet, so I came home and wrote this.

I saw other examples online, but this is the solution I came up with. It works from what I can see, and for these test values.

Did I make any mistakes? How can I improve my coding style and algorithm?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

    int main()
    {
      int intnumbers[10]= { 10,11, 17,20,37,53,44,88,90,42 }; 
      for(int i=0;i<10;i++)
      {
         if(intnumbers[i]%2==1){
          if((intnumbers[i]%3==1) || (intnumbers[i]%3==2) )
          {
              std::cout<<intnumbers[i] <<std::endl;      }
         }

      }
      }
```

Comment: What is the exercise that is being solved by this code?

Answer (score 3):

Style improvements:

- The use of whitespace here is inconsistent:

  > ```
  > int intnumbers[10]= { 10,11, 17,20,37,53,44,88,90,42 };
  > ```

  It's good to pay attention to detail by keeping it consistent:

  ```
  int intnumbers[10] = { 10, 11, 17, 20, 37, 53, 44, 88, 90, 42 };
  ```

  The spacing in between will make it a little more readable, even though it may increase the horizontal width.
- This could also use some whitespace:

  > ```
  > for(int i=0;i<10;i++)
  > ```

  It's good to keep one space between operators and operands so that they can be easily distinguished at first glance.

  ```
  for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
  ```
- Stick to one length of indentation.  For instance, I see two below the first `{`, just one after the first `if`, and four after the second `if`.  Four is most common in C++, so consider using that everywhere.
- You can increase performance a little by outputting `'\n'` instead of `std::endl`.  The latter also flushes the buffer, whereas the former does not.
- Want to stay ahead of the C++ game a bit (at least in a classroom setting)?  Use a container class such as an [`std::vector`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector) in place of the C array:

  ```
  const std::vector<int> intnumbers { 10, 11, 17, 20, 37, 53, 44, 88, 90, 42 };
  ```

  It may not matter that much in this small program without any functions, but it's a good habit for C++ programming.  You'll even benefit from various member functions and bounds-checking.

Answer (score 1):

Before we go into your algorithm, lets clean up your formatting:

```
// remove the extraneous <string> import
#include <iostream>

int main() {
    // clean up spacing and indentation
    int numbers[10] = {10, 11, 17, 20, 37, 53, 44, 88, 90, 42}; 
    for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        if (numbers[i] % 2 == 1) {
            if ((numbers[i] % 3 == 1) || (numbers[i] % 3 == 2)) {
                std::out << numbers[i] << std::end;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

In addition, checking if a number is 1 mod 3 or 2 mod 3 is the same as checking its not 0 mod 3 (divisible by 3).

Thus your code is basically:

```
for every number
   if its not divisible by 2 or 3, print it out.
```

Now what happens if our number is a multiple of 5? For example, 25 will get printed out even though it clearly isn't prime, as it's 5*5.

Thus you need a more robust algorithm.

If all your numbers are less than N, you only need to check all the prime divisors up to the square root. This is a mathematical fact whose proof is left as an exercise.

Since these numbers are less than 100, you only need to check divisibility by 2, 3, 5, or 7.

If you want a more robust algorithm, check 2 and all odd numbers up to and including the square root of the number. If the number doesn't divide any of these, it is prime.

Comment: Thanks for the input, i didnt include enough test variables